# Grails SpringSecurity Rest Basic auth + Login Form

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have the following problem in a Grails app with Spring Security (SSC). My app should provide some browseable pages as well as a Restful API.

While using the App with the Browser the App should display the Login-Form which is used by SSC and the Login/Logout Controller. But I also want to use alternativly a BasiAuthentication with the same URI.

For example: If I do a call to /myApp/testCall, coming from the Browser it should display the Login Form in case of a not already logged in user. If the user is logged in, it should process normally. But if I call /myApp/testCall with a Authorization Header then the App should recognize this and Authenticate the user by Basic Auth.

What I already got so far, whether the Basic Auth or the Login Form standalone, but not with this wanted bahviour. As soon as I activate the basiAuth in my App, it displays all the time the default Login form the Browser (Basic Auth Browser Login) but it should display the LoginForm.

Hope someone can help me solving this problem, I need somehow to put the Filter, which is responsible for displaying the Login Form in front of the Basic Auth Filter, but in the other case if I provide Basic Auth Credentials it should just log me in.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999342/restricting-data-returned-from-a-grails-restful-service-with-angularjs/23000616?noredirect=1#23000616) last week, not totally the answer to your question but it might help you get started.  Would have added this as a comment but I don't have the rep.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less similiar to my problme. My solution for now was just to divide the UrlMappings into two parts. One part for the API (Just with Basic Auth) and one for Browseable part.

Comment: Also found a great blog post: http://asoftwareguy.com/2014/03/17/using-grails-rest-for-authentication-in-an-angularjs-spa/

Comment: I also read this, tanks. Just for now I changed the Url-scheme as mentioned and finally run into this bug, which was also responsible for my first problem I think. [SpringSecurity Bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-210)